# sqlite with LIKE statement in xcode for iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, bind

First (of many?) posts here.

I have an issue with my statement.

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *query = "select * from words where ordet LIKE ?001";

    NSString *wildcard = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", fullWordForSQL.text];
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [wildcard UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ){
        NSLog(@"in if");
        NSLog(@"Data: %s", query);
```

I have successfully retrieved data with the query:

```
const char *query = "select * from words where ordet LIKE "_test__";
```

But when I try to bind the dynamicly created word it doesnt stick.
My nslog prints "Data: select * from words where ordet LIKE ?001" so somehow I am not getting the bind to work.
I know that there will be other issues along the way with the code above but right now Im stuck at this problem

Answer (score 2):

`query` does not change when you call `sqlite3_bind_text()`. If you think about it, there's no way it should change, since you declared it as a `const char *`. What you want to do is use `sqlite3_trace()` to register to get a callback with the final bound string so you can see what's really happening.

Comment: I dont know what you mean. My english might be rusty. I know sql from php but this is new to me. I am learning by doing...

Comment: Calling `sqlite3_bind_text()` does not modify `query`. It creates a new statement object. Your `NSLog()` prints `query`, which will always be the original text. If you want to see the bound result, you should look at `sqlite3_trace()` which will send you this string before processing it.

Comment: didnt find much on trace... :-(
maybe I am going in the wrong direction since it most likely is a simple typo or something since others have it working

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need to surround the value in single-quotes?  " where ordet like '%001' "   Or is that unnecessary in xcode? I am not proficient at xcode. Are you trying to inject the wildcard character into the sql statement in front of a value that is already contained in the statement string, or are you trying to prepend the wildcard character to a search-value and then bind that search-value-with-wildcard to the statement? It looks like the former to me, but as I said, I don't know xcode. I would not normally include a piece of the search-term in the query statement, but would do this:

```
       "select * from words where ordet like ?"

      // prepend the wildcard to my search term
      // bind the search term to my query
```

Comment: actually I am copying examples from other sites and many of them have satisfied users, but in my case it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your prepare_v2 statement BEFORE your bind_text statment.

Comment: actually I was testing code examples but realized that I didnt want the extra parameter like that. I built the query with known variables now and its working. Accept for one thing wich I am about to throw out a question on. :) thanks for the help though...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much simpler.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM words WHERE ordet GLOB '*%@*' ", fullWordForSQL.text];
```